# foreach loop for Facebook data in array

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, laravel, foreach

I am making a facebook graph api call and getting back the data. But for some reason cannot loop through it. is it because it is protected? Or my foreach loops are wrong.

This is the data when i var_export($user_pages) in my view

```
array (size=2)
  'data' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[92]
          public 'access_token' => string 'EAAZAbF70RRXMBADY1VdKYpEF2gKsM2n6ygicG2ZB94D6wrzBUSYg5Xn3psz7p8pGRpmjaZCP2U9JTrlPsvhm3345CyMIKVTGQk4GOZAS3BxNM4fZAZCKPRQQriFpaTnSfYMDhtnWZCgeZCM4hvt6r49LzaO7CttIy5MZD' (length=166)
          public 'category' => string 'Book Store' (length=10)
          public 'category_list' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => 
                object(stdClass)[93]
                  public 'id' => string '197048876974331' (length=15)
                  public 'name' => string 'Book Store' (length=10)
          public 'name' => string 'Unofficial Dev777' (length=17)
          public 'id' => string '1791907811022418' (length=16)
          public 'perms' => 
            array (size=6)
              0 => string 'ADMINISTER' (length=10)
              1 => string 'EDIT_PROFILE' (length=12)
              2 => string 'CREATE_CONTENT' (length=14)
              3 => string 'MODERATE_CONTENT' (length=16)
              4 => string 'CREATE_ADS' (length=10)
              5 => string 'BASIC_ADMIN' (length=11)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[94]
          public 'access_token' => string 'EAAZAbF70RRXMBAEZAVIJIx5vtvpZAjloLl0yjZBcErnxEzSiqZAQ9wRdo49Be5XXaO98ecQLN0zQVnjpViURgqilZBdfZAV8EuEriW13f0SlZCMoSUjenAp36X6RMeWI1DnxIrclW20vqL6hwgbfm9PZAxDB8lRUOcmkZD' (length=167)
          public 'category' => string 'Business Services' (length=17)
          public 'category_list' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => 
                object(stdClass)[95]
                  public 'id' => string '187133811318958' (length=15)
                  public 'name' => string 'Business Services' (length=17)
          public 'name' => string 'Self' (length=4)
          public 'id' => string '495868270618000' (length=15)
          public 'perms' => 
            array (size=6)
              0 => string 'ADMINISTER' (length=10)
              1 => string 'EDIT_PROFILE' (length=12)
              2 => string 'CREATE_CONTENT' (length=14)
              3 => string 'MODERATE_CONTENT' (length=16)
              4 => string 'CREATE_ADS' (length=10)
              5 => string 'BASIC_ADMIN' (length=11)
  'paging' => 
    object(stdClass)[96]
      public 'cursors' => 
        object(stdClass)[97]
          public 'before' => string 'MTc5MTkwNzgxMTAyMjQxOAZDZD' (length=26)
          public 'after' => string 'NDk1ODY4MjcwNjE4MDAw' (length=20
```

var_export($user_pages)

```
array ( 'data' => array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'access_token' => 'EAAZAbF70RRXMBAAesxifymoAnCRnrbp7n8t8sUG3gYkImVVZA1CxkUAmqZBA1SUdh7HZCg3EBHrpAcWiIHb2A5Secyhnx70qGW7hyTStE5KX842ZB5mlzO1RZAjkIsaWzN7e5uZCHZAfbQXLQo7We54ZACDjkbQ4TLIwZD', 'category' => 'Book Store', 'category_list' => array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'id' => '197048876974331', 'name' => 'Book Store', )), ), 'name' => 'Unofficial Dev777', 'id' => '1791907811022418', 'perms' => array ( 0 => 'ADMINISTER', 1 => 'EDIT_PROFILE', 2 => 'CREATE_CONTENT', 3 => 'MODERATE_CONTENT', 4 => 'CREATE_ADS', 5 => 'BASIC_ADMIN', ), )), 1 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'access_token' => 'EAAZAbF70RRXMBACzv5AV8MGVBTh1U4XgCXh7a9gs9R5JAQZBKf7gsdOhe6DKxk1Sy0cD2QtaDoHZBs6O13hWoL3W39M0WgNtpUssWam2PMskfEF6zZBypmLIiyQlj2ZC2Dq5tqTjH2WohusLdwyrODi4d9kzgBH4ZD', 'category' => 'Business Services', 'category_list' => array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'id' => '187133811318958', 'name' => 'Business Services', )), ), 'name' => 'Self', 'id' => '495868270618000', 'perms' => array ( 0 => 'ADMINISTER', 1 => 'EDIT_PROFILE', 2 => 'CREATE_CONTENT', 3 => 'MODERATE_CONTENT', 4 => 'CREATE_ADS', 5 => 'BASIC_ADMIN', ), )), ), 'paging' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'cursors' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'before' => 'MTc5MTkwNzgxMTAyMjQxOAZDZD', 'after' => 'NDk1ODY4MjcwNjE4MDAw', )), )), )
```

And this is my loop which throws an error saying "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Library/WebServer/Documents/fbLogin/app/views/hello.blade.php)
"

```
@foreach($user_pages as $pages)
                {{ $pages->name }}
                {{ $pages->category }}
@endforeach
```

I have also tried var_dump($user_pages->backingData) it shows error saying "Cannot access protected property Facebook\GraphObject::$backingData"

is the data not accessible?

**have posted result for var_export
** okay I have used the facebook asArray() method while calling graph api and the data is more readable now. Will just need to loop through it.
*** have updated post with the new var_dump after the asArray()

Comment: try to make a `var_export()` to try the response

Comment: how will that help?

Comment: what I mean is you to post the [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) instead of the var_dump, for me to try to iterate your array

Comment: have posted the var_export() result

Answer (score 0):

Changed my api request **to**

```
return $response->getGraphObject()->getProperty('data')->asArray();
```

**from**

```
return $response->getGraphObject();
```

getting the data in a simple array form now, through which I am easily looping using foreach

```
@foreach($user_pages as $user_pages)
                {{ $user_pages->name }}
                {{ $user_pages->category }}
@endforeach
```